# Show loading indicator in Phonegap InAppBrowser

Tags: android, cordova, loading

I am trying to display a loading indicator in Phonegap InAppBrowser when a page is loading using the following code:

```
    var ref;
    ref = window.open('http://www.google.com', '_top', 'location=no');
    ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) { 
        //navigator.splashscreen.show();
        navigator.notification.activityStart("", "loading");
    });
    ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) { 
        //navigator.splashscreen.hide();
    navigator.notification.activityStop();
    });
```

It doesn't display the indicator. I think that the z-index is lower then z-index of InAppBrowser.

If I use a splash screen instead of loading indicator it works.

Answer (score 10):

You can open `InAppBrowser` in `hidden` mode, meanwhile display a spinner, and when it finishes loading hide the spinner and show the `InAppBrowser`:

```
showSpinner() // implement by yourself
var popup = window.open(url, "_blank", "location=no,toolbar=no,hidden=yes");
popup.addEventListener("loadstop", function() {
  popup.show();
  hideSpinner(); // implement by yourself
});
```

Comment: opening inappbrowser in hidden mode leads to some other issue in my case, I need a to inject script/html to show a loaded, any help?

Answer (score 2):

For me, hiding inappbrowser was giving some uncaught error if the page being loaded redirects to another! I had to keep the inappbrowser visible. I was able to inject a spinner to the inappbrowser for improving the user experience by avoiding the awkward white screen.

**Custom Spinner**

following solution has many alternatives, one can use an html file 'spinner.html' instead of  hard-coding the code, but this specific approach is working across platform (nexus 5, pixel 1/2, iphone 6,7)

```
//use some really slow page for testing
var path="https://www.facebook.com/";

//if you have a spinner.html, you can load that instead of path here in inappbrowser, but make sure it works in all devices.

var ref = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(path, '_blank', 'toolbarposition=top,closebuttoncaption=Back,location=no,hardwareback=no');

//spinner html
var spinner ="<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta name='viewport' content='width=device-width,height=device-height,initial-scale=1'><style>.loader {position: absolute;    margin-left: -2em;    left: 50%;    top: 50%;    margin-top: -2em;    border: 5px solid #f3f3f3;    border-radius: 50%;    border-top: 5px solid #3498db;    width: 50px;    height: 50px;    -webkit-animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;    animation: spin 1.5s linear infinite;}@-webkit-keyframes spin {  0% { -webkit-transform: rotate(0deg); } 100% { -webkit-transform: rotate(360deg); }}@keyframes spin {  0% { transform: rotate(0deg); }  100% { transform:rotate(360deg); }}</style></head><body><div class='loader'></div></body></html>";

//intended webpage is loaded here (facebook)
ref.executeScript({code: "(function() {document.write(\""+spinner+"\");window.location.href='"+path+"';})()"});

//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstart', function(event) {
    //nothing specific needed for spinner                        
});

//loadstop event
ref.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event) {
    //nothing specific needed for spinner
});
```

spinner will be overwritten by the actual page once it starts loading.

Answer (score 0):

have a look in the link it explain its in detail. This loading screen do not work with ios but its working absolutely fine on android 
http://javacourseblog.blogspot.in/2014/02/show-loading-screen-in-phonegap-app.html