# Cordova InAppBrowser hidden until it finished to load

Tags: android, ios, cordova, inappbrowser

I'm using cordova to open a remote url inside my app. My problem is that I obtain a blank screen during the few secondsof content loading.

Is there a way to "hide" the browser view during the time it finishes to load the content ?

Thank you

Comment: Hiding the inappbrowser can lead to other complications if the page being loaded has a redirect. 
Check out this answer
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21281571/show-loading-indicator-in-phonegap-inappbrowser/50580198#50580198 if you are interested in adding a spinner instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is `hidden` parameter:

```
var options = "location=yes,hidden=yes";

inAppBrowserRef = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(url, target, options);

addEventListener('loadstop', loadStopCallBack);

function loadStopCallBack() {

    inAppBrowserRef.show();
}
```

See the [plugin docs](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser#example-1) for example details.